# How to redirect user to different home pages after logging in based on their roles?

Tags: c#, sql-server, authentication

I have created a database table called [reg] which is storing user details including roles. There is a column in that table called Role, they are two roles which are parent and teacher. So i want to redirect them to different homepages based on their role. How can i do that?? Pls help.

This is my login.cs code as below:

```
public partial class Login : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection();

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    protected void ButtonLogin_Click1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        con.ConnectionString = "Data Source=DESKTOP-H7KQUT1;Initial Catalog=Registration;Integrated Security=True";
        con.Open();
        string checkuser = "select count(*) from [reg] where Username = '" + TextBoxUser.Text + "'";
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(checkuser, con);
        int temp = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString());
        if (temp == 1)
        {
            string checkPasswordQuery = "select Pass from [reg] where Username= '" + TextBoxUser.Text + "'";
            SqlCommand passCom = new SqlCommand(checkPasswordQuery, con);
            string password = passCom.ExecuteScalar().ToString().Replace(" ","");
            if (password == TextBoxPass.Text)
            {
                Session["New"] = TextBoxUser.Text;
                Session["Username"] = TextBoxUser.Text;
                MessageBox.Show("Password is correct");
                Response.Redirect("HomeTeacher.aspx");

            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Password is not correct");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Username is not correct");
        }

        con.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Gah, the sql injection holes, they burns us!

Comment: Before you write another line of code you need to read about, understand and start using parameterized queries. Your code is a textbook example of sql injection. My friend bobby tables loves this type of thing. http://bobby-tables.com/

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn what do you mean injection holes?

Comment: And you really should not be storing passwords in clear text. They should be salted and hashed. I would also caution you against separate messages for username and password being invalid. That is the type of information that is extremely helpful if you are making a brute force attack. As soon as you get the password incorrect message you know that you have a valid username.

Comment: For the question at hand, you simply add some code at the end of your successful block to look up what page based on role (probably a table in the database) and then Response.Redirect

Comment: @SeanLange Thanks for your help!! By the way, do you have any idea or code example to help me to redirect different users to different page? I only have a table called [reg] and there is a column called 'Role' to differentiate users

Comment: As I said, you need to know the page for each role. That means you need that data in a table. Depending on your system you could add that as a column to the Role table. Or create a new table. Then you just query the value and call Response.Redirect. Pretty straight forward.

Answer (score 1):

There's a lot in here, so I added a lot of comments to explain the changes.

```
protected void ButtonLogin_Click1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Don't re-use the connection object. 
    // ADO.Net has a feature called connection pooling, and re-using the 
    // connection object interferes with it.
    // This is the rare case where you really do want to create
    // a new instance almost every time

    string checkuser = "select Role, Salt, PwdHash from [reg] where Username = @Username";
    string role = "", goodHash = "", salt = "";

    //The using blocks will make sure the connection is closed, 
    // **even if an exception is thrown**.
    using (var con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=DESKTOP-H7KQUT1;Initial Catalog=Registration;Integrated Security=True"))
    using (var cmd = new SqlCommand(checkuser, con))
    { 
        //**ALWAYS** use parameters like this to include data in the query that
        // has any chance to be influenced in any way by the user
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Username",SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50).Value = TextBoxUser.Text;

        con.Open();
        using (var rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
        {
            if (!rdr.Read()) // no record for this user
            {
                //Common practice is to NOT make it obvious whether the username or password was wrong,
               // though there is debate in security circles whether that's really necessary.
               //Also, **DON'T USE MESSAGEBOX IN WEB APPS!**
               // It doesn't work at all the way you think. 
               Response.Redirect("InvalidLogin.aspx");
               return;
           }

           //For convenience, I'll assume nothing is NULL if we actually have a record
           //Done right, the salt and password are often byte arrays, but base64 strings are common, too.
           salt = (string)rdr["Salt"]; 
           goodHash = (string)rdr["PwdHash"];
           role = (string)rdr["Role"];
        }
    }

    //You'll need to write this function on your own,
    // but there are libraries on NuGet that make it easy
    var attemptedHash = GetBCryptHash(salt, TextBoxPass.Text);
    if (attemptedHash != goodHash)
    {
        Response.Redirect("InvalidLogin.aspx");
        return;
    }

    Session["New"] = TextBoxUser.Text;
    Session["Username"] = TextBoxUser.Text;
    Session["Role"] = role;

    if (role == "Teacher")
    {
        Response.Redirect("HomeTeacher.aspx");
    }
    else
    {
        Response.Redirect("HomeStudent.aspx");
    }
}
```

Here it is again without all the extra comments:

```
protected void ButtonLogin_Click1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string checkuser = "select Role, Salt, PwdHash from [reg] where Username = @Username";
    string role = "", goodHash = "", salt = "";

    using (var con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=DESKTOP-H7KQUT1;Initial Catalog=Registration;Integrated Security=True"))
    using (var cmd = new SqlCommand(checkuser, con))
    { 
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Username",SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50).Value = TextBoxUser.Text;
        con.Open();
        using (var rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
        {
            if (!rdr.Read()) // no record for this user
            {
               Response.Redirect("InvalidLogin.aspx");
               return;
            }

            salt = (string)rdr["Salt"]; 
            goodHash = (string)rdr["PwdHash"];
            role = (string)rdr["Role"];
        }
    }

    // You still need to write this function, and you'll still want to rely on nuget
    var attemptedHash = GetBCryptHash(salt, TextBoxPass.Text);
    if (attemptedHash != goodHash)
    {
        Response.Redirect("InvalidLogin.aspx");
        return;
    }

    Session["New"] = TextBoxUser.Text;
    Session["Username"] = TextBoxUser.Text;
    Session["Role"] = role;

    if (role == "Teacher")
    {
        Response.Redirect("HomeTeacher.aspx");
    }
    else
    {
        Response.Redirect("HomeStudent.aspx");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to redirect users based on their role is very simple:

```
string getUserRole = "SELECT Role from [reg] where Username= @User";
Using;
    SqlCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCommand(sql, con);
    sqlCmd.Parameters.Add("@User", SqlDbType.String).Value = TextBoxUser.Text;
    String userRole = roleCmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString().Replace(" ","");
End Using;
con.Close();
if userRole = your_user_role
    //redirect 1
else
   // redirect 2
```

I suggest you to take a look at:

`sqlCmd.Parameters.Add("@User", SqlDbType.String).Value = TextBoxUser.Text;`

It's higlhy raccomandable to **ALWAYS** use parameters.

Take this line as an example and add parameters on every query where you need to take data from user input.